# How to check if a string has '\' in python?

Tags: python, string, backslash

I know that I can print '\' like this:

`print('\\')`

But the same logic doesn't work when I try to check if '\' is in a string, like this:

`if '\\' in 'blaablaa\something'`

So how can I do that?

Comment: It works for me, why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you state your input and the desired output? `'\\' in 'blaablaa\something'` equates to `True`

Comment: You can assert that '\\' in 'blaablaa\something' == True therefore I can't see your problem

Comment: can you show your code and error?

Comment: Are you sure your actual string has `\s`, not something like `\n`? That escape sequence will turn into newline. I recommend you use raw strings so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: `\s` doesn't put a `\\` in the string.

Comment: @Barmar I wish I knew an easy way to teach people the difference between string content and string representation. A lot get tripped up by it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually it does, since `\s` isn't an escape sequence. I originally wrote a similar comment, but deleted it.

Comment: @Barmar and that's half the problem, sometimes you can get away with it and sometimes you can't.

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed, that's why I said "use raw strings so you don't have to worry about this":

Comment: @Barmar but how do you get Python to *print* a raw string?  That's what causes a lot of the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raw literal.

```
'\\' in r'blaablaa\something'
```

This would return true.

Comment: And note you can't use `r'\'` because of a quirk in Python's syntax.

Comment: Maybe this could change with the new parser.